# UICollectionView display previous cell content in next cell while scroll horizontally

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, scrollview

I am using a `UICollectionView` to show an **array of images**, **horizontally** and zoom in/out that image in the cell with the help of **scroll** view using **constraints**. But when I scroll horizontally it shows me previous cell content in the current cell.  I am  and not able to identify what is the problem. [image]

[image]

> CollectionView datasources

[image]

> CollectionCell Class
>   [image]

Comment: please share some code to better understand...!!!

Comment: In particular your `cellForItem(at:)` function

Comment: Overriding "prepareForReuse" method inside image cell with resetting the things like 
1). scrollViewForImage.zoomscale = 1
2). imageView.image = nil
3). remove added tap gesture from image view

Should fix the problem

Answer (score 0):

try this when you reuse the Cell in cellForItem at

cell.imageView.Image = nil

Comment: cell.imageView.Image = nil
cell.steupdata()

Comment: Yeah! I did exactly the same but it not solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Please share some code so that we can help you better. Meanwhile, make sure you have the following parts working correctly in your code:

- Register correct UICollectionViewCell subclass with correct reuse identifier
- Use the method `[self.collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:itemIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath]` and pass both the parameters correctly.
- In UICollectionViewCell subclass, override `prepareForReuse` and reset the UI parameters there.

  Override `prepareForReuse` in imageCell class, and set imageView.image to nil.

Comment: I have edited my question with a couple of code. Please have a look on it

Comment: image view is displayed correct image on every scroll but the content size scroll is being wrong!

Comment: Maybe you need to `invalidateIntrinsicContentSize`, recalculate the size, and call `setNeedsLayout`.

Answer (score 0):

The contentSize of the scrollView should be as big as imageView.image.size, or just use `MWPhotoBrowser`